# Debezium PostgresConnector instantiate topics as there is no data in tables

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm creating a CDC  Postgres.source --> Kafka / Debezium --> Postgres.sink.

source topic are well created but only when the table has data.
Is there a way to instantiate all topics even though there is no data.
Because I would like to download all AVRO schemas with maven command :

```
mvn schema-registry:download
```

My config :

```
{
  "name": "postgres-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.hostname": "postgres-source",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.dbname" : "postgres",
    "database.server.name": "postgres",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.customers",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Topics aren't associated with schemas, the relationship is the other way, so there is nothing to "instantiate" them from the database alone.

You would need some other method of execution if you are wanting to create Kafka topics prior to starting the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If I may add to the answer from OneCricketeer, schemas are attached to the record, not the topic. You can have a Kafka topic that is contains records with different schemas (ideally compatible in some ways).

As the schema is record dependent, it requires the data to be published to debezium first. I would suggest to create the schema first using other tools, or if you have separate environment that can be used to generate the schema by writing a dummy row without polluting the topic.